# Converting Trac Wiki into Sphinx project

Tags: python-sphinx, trac

Is there tool support for the conversion of Trac Wiki pages into reStructuredText or Sphinx pages?
There is a tool for the conversion of Trac to MediaWiki and this works quite well.
Thus, a conversion from MediaWiki to `.rst` would be nice as well.

Answer (score 1):

After consulting with some friends, I found out that [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can convert MediaWiki to reStructuredText.